# Installing Cube from a .gz file on Linux

Tags: linux, troubleshooting

[image]I need help installing a `.gz` file on my computer through Linux. I have run every command up to the `./configure`.(install tar.gz or just .gz)

```
tar xfvz file name.gz
cd file name
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

When I run `./configure` it tells me **No such file or directory** and I have tried using the `sudo apt-get install build-essential` command but when I tried using the `./configure` again it still gave me the same thing. I don't know what else to do, I am trying to install a game called cube output

```
ls -l danielblain156@penguin:~/cube$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 danielblain156 danielblain156  236 Aug 13  2005 autoexec.cfg
drwxr-xr-x 1 danielblain156 danielblain156  124 Aug 29  2005 bin_unix
-rwxr-xr-x 1 danielblain156 danielblain156  807 Aug 24  2005 cube_unix
drwxr-xr-x 1 danielblain156 danielblain156  298 Aug 22  2005 data
drwxr-xr-x 1 danielblain156 danielblain156    0 May 25  2004 demos
drwxr-xr-x 1 danielblain156 danielblain156  120 Aug 22  2005 docs
drwxr-xr-x 1 danielblain156 danielblain156  334 Aug 14  2005 packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 danielblain156 danielblain156 6386 Aug 22  2005 readme.html
drwxr-xr-x 1 danielblain156 danielblain156    0 Aug 14  2005 savegames
drwxr-xr-x 1 danielblain156 danielblain156    0 Aug 22  2005 screenshots
```

Comment: If you get **No such file or directory** is because the file `./configure` does not exist. Maybe you forgot to change to the directory where `./configure` is.

Comment: Add to your **question** the output of this command: `ls -l`

Comment: i ran the cd cube command and it took me to the file directory but from there i really don't know what to do. i am just a beginner when it comes to stuff like this sorry

Comment: *"I ran the cd cube command and it took me to the file directory"* when you do that please run the command: `ls -l` and the output to your question (`-l` is the lowercase of `L` not the number one)

Comment: In the `ls -l` output does not show `./configure`. Where are you following the instructions from?  Can you provide the link where you are downloading the game?

Comment: here you go https://www.myabandonware.com/game/cube-gc9#Linux

Comment: I'd suggest reading the *readme.html* in the hopes that it holds instructions. That said: There's a pretty good chance that a 17 year old binary won't work on your current Linux installation ...

Comment: i've added the readme.html for you. like i said before i don't really undertsnad all of this but i am trying to learn

Comment: @Decku as tink said aybe running that old game won't work in your Linux. I tried to run `./cube_unix` and my machine does not support it. The game seems to admin only these architectures: `i486,i586,i686`.

Comment: oh ok well thank you for all of your help and hope you have a great day

Comment: @Decku same! Btw, If you want to play that game I think you can install a vritual machine to use one of those architectures (and download a Linux iso that supports those arch).  You can see about `qemu,qemu-kvm`

Comment: @Decku Not sure if [this game](https://assault.cubers.net/) is the same (Assault Cube), the screenshots looks similar.

Comment: Or maybe you can try running `Cube` under `wine` in Linux. You will have to download the file for Windows and run the exe with wine. But not sure if that will work.

Comment: i don't like to use wine for every time i go to install or uninstall it i have problems getting it to work and thanks i'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

wherever you have these instructions from, they don't apply to you (they are for building a program from source code if that source code already contains an executable script named `configure`. Your program doesn't seem to need building, nor does it contain a `configure` script… so, wrong solution).

The thing you do was written before 64-bit processors were standard, it seems, and it for some reason has a broken detection whether you're on Linux. OK!

You would just need to run `./bin_unix/linux_client`, it  seems, from reading the `cube_unix` script. However, that seems to stand alone, and not contain any information on what libraries it needs.

You essentially got incomplete software. That's not a problem with what you did or your Linux – it's just not containing all the files necessary, nor info where to get the missing stuff, and on what platforms this even used to run.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on what you really need to install to make this work, and there's no guarantee on binary compatibility, anyways.

So, trying to make this run will need an expert, and probably a bit of archaeology to find a linux system that still ships these things.

(Having said that: What comes next probably doesn't help you much. A quick binary analysis shows insufficient error reporting on failing to load a library, so you're not even told what is still missing. Just extracting strings that might point to libraries (because they are strings and contain `.so.`), you would need binary-compatible 32-bit versions of *at least* these libraries:

- libSDL-1.2.so.0
- libSDL_image-1.2.so.0
- libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0
- libz.so.1
- libGL.so.1
- libGLU.so.1
- libstdc++.so.5
- libgcc_s.so.1
- libX11.so.6

So, without being able to dig out an older Linux distro, you will not have success running this on your machine.)

Normally I'd just say "Just email the developer really nicely, point them to your question here and ask politely if they could help you out with information on what system this was developed", but honestly, the title of that page you downloaded this from is literally "My Abandonware". (So it's just a collection of other people's software, which the site owner does not have a connection to, necessarily.)

Also, reading the comments: this is architecturally not a game designed for modern PCs at all! It runs as fast as it can on your machine, which will probably be very fast with modern PCs and graphics cards, and expects the user to adjust sleep times between frames manually. These kinds of games need to make a lot of assumption, and stand a rather high chance of not only (if not adjusted) being unplayably fast on a modern PC, but also buggy.

The way to go here might really be emulation of a native platform. Grab a Linux installer image from 2003, something like debian 3.0 (woody) if you want a permanent installation, or Knoppix 3.5, if just saving the virtual machine state suffices for your use cases.

Easiest case for emulation: you find an old DVD image of "Games Knoppix 4" (or so). I think that contained Cube. Install virtualbox on your linux, boot that disk, play Cube.

By the way, Cube was continued (if you read the original website instead of the "my abandonware" copy) and was renamed to Sauerbraten. I don't know which Linux distribution you're using, but for example on a Ubuntu, `sudo apt install sauerbraten` should give you that, with no detour.